# How would one do html input tag autocomplete in Ext.js?

Tags: ajax, extjs, autocomplete

If you're using the Ext.js library, how does one do autocomplete in input text areas?

More precisely, how would one do autocomplete based on iterative Ajax requests (like the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/AutoComplete/autocomplete) where the Ajax option is set to an updating url).

Thoughts are appreciated and thank you for reading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since bmoueskau provided a quite full featured implementation, I thought a more bare-bones example could help.

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: '/your/ajax/script/',
    root: 'data',  // the root of the array you'll send down
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: ['id','value']
});

var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    store: store,
    displayField:'value',
    typeAhead: true,
    mode: 'remote',
    queryParam: 'query',  //contents of the field sent to server.
    hideTrigger: true,    //hide trigger so it doesn't look like a combobox.
    selectOnFocus:true,
    width: 250,
    renderTo: 'autocomplete'  //the id of the html element to render to.
                              //Not necessary if this is in an Ext formPanel.
});
```

The store will accept responses from your server formatted like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "value": "Automobile"
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "value": "Autocomplete"
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course, you could also set up your store with an Ext.data.XMLReader if that's more your style.

I hope that gets you started.  I can't stress enough the awesomeness of the [Ext documentation](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/output/Ext.form.ComboBox.html).  It's got some pertinent examples in addition to the [combobox samples](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.html), which I used heavily when I first made some autocompleters.

Answer (score 6):

There is no separate autocomplete functionality that can be attached generically to inputs -- you would just use a ComboBox control with server-side filtering (you can use the "hideTrigger: true" config so that it still looks like a plain input).  This is probably the closest example to what you'd want:

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/forum-search.html

Comment: Additionally, I think it could be set for local filtering too.

Comment: Thanks bmoeskau for the input. I've put up a bounty to see if I can get an example or two.