# Ext JS auto complete field with additional post variables

Tags: ajax, extjs, combobox, autocomplete

I am using an Ext JS ComboBox like in this Example: [stackoverflow: How would one do html input tag autocomplete in Ext.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313025/how-would-one-do-html-input-tag-autocomplete-in-ext-js)

It works perfect for sending a simple query over POST to the server. (Firebug output: query=smth)

But now I have a bit different use case. I want to send some additional information to the server. Something like: query=smth&variableId=8&someMore=XY.

Of course I could just add the variables to the URL of the JsonStore and send it over GET. But I am wondering if there is something like a params object where I can specify my custom variables and which will be considered for the request.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can define your store with

```
baseParams: {
   thisWillBeAddedToEachRequest: 'foo'
}
```

Or you can use `beforeload` listener

```
listeners: {
  beforeload: funciton(store) {
    store.setBaseParam('paramToBeSetBeforeEachRequest',someVariable);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactely what I was hoping for.